# EF core 2, возможно ли задать косвенную связь между сущностями через свойство навигации?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Есть необходимость создать логическую связь между сущностью А и набором сущностей Б без FK по кастомному условию?

Если абстрактное описание не понятно, вот пример

```
class Entity1
{
  public int Start { get; set; }
  public int End { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Entity2> Nested { get; set; }
}

class Entity2
{
  public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

где в Nested попадут сущности Entity2, у которых свойство Value входит в интервал между Start и End.

Просьба не минусовать, если вопрос глупый, а объяснить, почему он глупый (типа, "так тут же трекинг накроется сразу").

Comment: Думаю, автоматически - а-ля Навигационное свойство - это сделать нельзя. Но можно написать запрос, который заполнит эту коллекцию.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну да, так то понятно, просто хотелось делать это через Include при необходимости.Да и в остальном тоже (Select, Order, Where)